# Arranging non uniform xtics to a uniform scale in GNUPlot

Tags: gnuplot, scale

I have a data set that uses the x-scale:

> 0.1 0.4 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20

But I need the tics to line up evenly, not have 0.1 and 0.4 scrunched up into the corner. I currently use,

```
set xtics 1
set xtics add (0.1)(0.4)
```

But that spaces 0.1 and 0.4 respective to the rest of the scale. I've attached a link to a tinypic I uploaded of my dummy data set with my current problem.

http://tinypic.com/r/2zfolxf/7

Comment: It is not clear to me what exactly you are trying to do. Do you want the 0.1 and 0.4 tic to be aligned as if they were the values 1 and 2 but displayed as 0.1 and 0.4? Either clarify what you are after or check the xtics documentation [here](http://www.gnuplot.info/docs_4.2/gnuplot.html#x1-29800043.89).

Comment: I am asking if there is a way (and if there is, how) to arrange the x-axis scale to have 0.1 and 0.4 lined up with the rest of the axis' scale.

For clarity, I wish to have 0.1 and 0.4 to have a position on the axis as if they were whole numbers (spaced evenly with the rest of the numbers) as if 0.1 were -1 and 0.4 were 0, so that the graph would start at "-1"(0.1, in case that's confusing).

The only caveat is that I can't simply change the numbers and "pretend" that they mean 0.1 and 0.4. I need the plotted points on the graph to be at those positions as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Current State

As far as I know, you can do the following in gnuplot with tics (at least what is relevant to your question):

- You can specify the *start*, *increment* and *end* of the tics displayed.
  This would make sense to you, if you wish to simply set the tics after the value of 2 like

  ```
  set xtics 2, 1
  ```
- The other thing you can do, is add explicit tic labels to certain values like

  ```
  set xtics add ("0.1" 0, "0.4" 1)
  ```

  This would introduce the labels *0.1*, and *0.4* to the x scale where the actual values are *0* and *1*

However you cannot modify the actual plotting of the graph. If in you data it states

```
0.1 100
0.4 150
1   200
2   300
```

then gunplot will plot it correspondingly.

### Possible workaround

A workaround could look like this:

1. Plot the normal graph from *2* upwards.
2. Do some hackery stuff to the first two values with this:

   ```
   plot "Data.dat" every 1::2 w l, "" every 1::1::2 using ($1<magic>):($2)
   ```

*magic* specifies some algebraic operation you want to do with the first column.
Everything is allowed and if your values are constant you can specify a polynomial that goes through the points 0, 1 and 2 with the inputs 0.1, 0.4 and 1 like this polynomial:

```
y = -1.85*x^2 + 4.26*x - 1.4
```

### Example

Suppose you have this data file:

```
0.1 0.41
0.4  0.03
1 0.97
2  0.74
3  0.05
4  0.15
5   0.11 
6 0.60
7 0.76
8 0.25
```

Then you can "rearrange" the first two entries to the x-positions -1 and 0 like this:

```
plot "Data.dat" every 1::2 w l, \
"" every 1::0::2 using (-1.85*$1**2 + 4.26*$1 - 1.4):($2) w l
```

With some tic-labeling and line style settings it should look exactly like what you are after.

I hope I understood what you are after and that you can make some use of my suggestions.
Cherio
Woltan

Comment: I figured it out myself, but your post was helpful knowledge in it's own. Thanks for the reply!